# subring of a finite ring that is division ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Is there any noncommutative ring of finite order whose subring is a division ring?
I started with taking matrix ring but not been able to get the answer yet.

Comment: "Whose subring..." ? Did you mean "with a subring that is a division ring"? Anyway, matrices rings over finite fields/rings seem to be a good idea to check and work with. FYI, any finite integral domain is a field, but of course a field is also a division ring.

Comment: Quaternions over some finite field where $-1$ is not a square, perhaps?

Comment: Also note, that every finite division ring is a field. This is the statement of Wedderburn’s little theorem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wedderburn's_little_theorem

Comment: @user218931 I think WLT talks of finite *domains*, not finite division rings in general. I don't know of the top of my head whether any finite division ring is also a domain (i.e., commutative)...

Comment: Domains need not be commutative. WLT proves in particular that every finite domain is commutative. Did you try to click on the link?

Comment: @Joanpemo it's very easy to show that a finite domain is s division ring, so the main thrust of WLT is to show commutativity.

Comment: @rschwieb Thank you, and I thought so. Apparently the top of your head is higher than mine. :)

Answer (score 0):

If $F_2$ is the field of two elements, then the matrix ring $M_2(F_2)$ is a finite ring that isn't commutative and contains the division ring $F_2$.

Of course, if when you say "division ring" you also mean "which isn't a field" then this is not possible: Wedderburn's Little Theorem says that a finite division ring is a field.

---

(Response to question in commments.)

Now switch to $F_3$ and look at $M_2(F_3)$. The matrix $A=\begin{bmatrix}0&-1\\1&0\end{bmatrix}$ has minimal polynomial $x^2+1$ which is irreducible over $F_3$. That means that the subring $\{\alpha I+\beta A\mid \alpha\beta\in F_3\}\subseteq M_2(F_3)$ is isomorphic to $F_3[x]/(x^2+1)$ which is the field $F_9$ of nine elements.

It is well-known that $\{\alpha I\mid \alpha\in F_3\}$ is the center of $M_2(F_3)$, so you can see that $A$ itself is not central in $M_2(F_3)$.

Comment: Thank you. Here $F_2$ will commute with every element in $M_2(F_2)$. Can  we get a subring (division ring) whose elemets donot commute with the elements of the ring?

Comment: @user341867 Not hard to adapt a new example that satisfies that too.

Comment: @ rschwieb Can you please show one?

Comment: @user341867 I have already added an example an hour before your comment that I'm presently responding to.